# Transpose Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas

I created a pandas pivot table using `pd.pivot_table`. My table has one dependent variable, and then three independent variables (1 for rows, 2 for columns). I want to export the table so all the values are in one row. However, when I try to `unstack()` the table, instead of moving the row variable to the columns, it moves all the columns variables to the rows - leaving all the values in one column instead.

Is there a way to transpose this so when I export it to excel all the values are in one row?

Comment: You can transpose a table with df.T

Comment: @NicholasAldershof Thanks, however when I try using `df.T`, the table comes back vertical still (with the data in one column). `mytable.unstack()` looks the same as `mytable.unstack().T`

Comment: please add an example of the current format and the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are producing a Series by stacking (or unstacking), which is actually one-dimensional and displays as a column. You could force to display as a row with something like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.stack()).T
```